# Jquery Cycle FX causing images to disappear?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I've added the jquery cycle plugin to my website with the idea of using it as a basic 'left-to-right' slideshow.  The problem is only some of the FX transitions seem to work.

http://www.petsdomain.com.au/natures_test/index.html

For example, currently i have the it set to:

```
$("ul#slides").cycle ({
    fx: 'fade',
    pause: 1,
    speed: 2000,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next',
    cleartypeNoBg: true,
});
```

If i try to change the fx to 'scrollLeft', the images in the slideshow disappear!  If i view the code in Chrome, it appears that the slideshow is working (you can see the code changing) but no images appear!

I'm happy to keep the effect as fade - but I would really like to know WHY this is happening for future projects...

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded the full jquery cycle js or the min version?  The min version only contains a limited number of effects.